# Android set intent filter on manifest to send mail

Tags: android, android-intent

My simple andoroid application can be internal email sender. I'm trying to set some intent filter on activity on manifest to used for other application, how can i set some intent filter to have this ability? i want to users can select my application to sending mail, I found this code, but seems it doesn't correct.

```
<intent-filter android:label="Send Mail" android:icon="@drawable/pig">
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -1):

Define intent filter in manifest

```
 <activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <!-- filter for sending text; accepts SENDTO action with sms URI schemes -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- filter for sending text or images; accepts SEND action and text or image data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Handle Result in your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get the intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        // Handle intents with text ...
    }
}
```

For more info go though the [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

It works fine & everything is defined in detail.

Comment: `<data android:scheme="sms" />` can be used for email?

Comment: No its for sending sms purpose, actually I used this for Sharing purpose as this action is for sharing. You can exclude this part according to your requirements.